# jquery.query-object plugin giving me problems when trying to replace a parameter in my URL's query string

Tags: jquery, url, replace, parameters, query-string

I'm using jQuery 1.12 and using thsi plugin -- https://plugins.jquery.com/query-object/ to help me replace/add a parameter in my query string, which I currently do by invoking the logic

```
new_url = $.query.set("order_by", data_val).toString() 
window.location.href = new_url
```

However, this logic is screwing up my query string for parameters that I don't touch.  For example, if I have the below URL

```
http://myurl?utf8=✓&first_name=&last_name=&search=Token&x=0&y=0
```

invoking the above logic turns the URL into

```
?utf8=%E2%9C%93&first_name&last_name&search=Token&x=0&y=0&order_by=name
```

Note taht the "first_name=" has been reduced to just "first_name".  Is there anotehr jQuery plugin I shoudl be using?  Basically I want to replace/add a parameter without touching the other parameters.

Comment: It is actually standardizing parameters.

Comment: ok but that is screwing up parameter processing on my server end of things

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is serializing parameters apart from appending to new params to the URL. If you don't want that behavior you can try below code to append new parameters

```js
var url = "http://myurl?utf8=✓&first_name=&last_name=&search=Token&x=0&y=0";

var addParam = function(url, params) {
  for (var i in params) {
    var char = url.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?';
    url += char + i + '=' + params[i];
  }
  return url;
}

console.log(addParam(url, {
  order: 'whatever',
  test: 1
}));
```